# Как сделать spinner без выпадающего меню в android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-spinner

Мне нужно сделать spinner без выпадающего меню, как здесь:
[image: spinner без выпадающего меню]

Я понимаю, что можно сделать из listview и функции по нажатию, но может есть какой-нибудь способ попроще?

Comment: кастомизированый RadioGroup здесь больше всего уместен будет

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит по функционалу как обычный RadioButton group, тем более что скорее всего категории фиксированные https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Как вариант набор Checkbox с логикой отключения другого checkbox
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox